# Mock the business layer for integration testing the Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, mocking, integration-testing

I want to do integration tests on my Web API without depending on my business layer interfaces.

When this action is run:

1) I want to mock the _service object and just verify that is is called

2) I want to assert that the correct StatusCode is returned

Number 2 is no problem but how can I mock the _service object (ISchoolyearService) when I do not control/start the creation of the api controller manually because this is a task done in unit testing the controller. But I do not want to unit test my API !

```
 [RoutePrefix("api/schoolyears")]
    public class SchoolyearController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly ISchoolyearService _service;
        public SchoolyearController(ISchoolyearService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }



 [Route("")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]SchoolyearCreateRequest request)
    {
        _service.CreateSchoolyear(request);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
    }
```

Comment: Do you deploy to a specific integration testing environment? You could simply add a key to your Web.Config that says IntegrationTesting=true on the specific testing env and when you define the injection for your `ISchoolyearService` you switch between your real implement or a mock service you created when IntegrationTesting == true.

Comment: "deploy to a specific integration testing environment" ? Do yo speak of testing selfhosting vs iis hosting? I am using the HttpServer and HttpClient to make my integration tests. But anyway I do not understand your suggestion how it can help me.

Comment: Well, what IoC do you use to inject your real service into ISchoolyearService? You can make it switch between a mock object or the real service depending on a key in your Web.Config. If your issue is about how to create mock objects, you can do it by hand or use of the many mocking framework, for example Moq: http://www.nuget.org/packages/MOQ. Maybe you can point me on the specifics of your problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following is a crude example of how you can do with in-memory integration testing. Here I am using `Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver` to inject mock dependencies. You can use any other IoC container similarly.

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using Unity.WebApi;

namespace WebApplication251.Tests.Controllers
{
    [TestClass]
    public class PeopleControllerTest
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://dummyhost/";

        [TestMethod]
        public void PostTest()
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

            // use the configuration that the web application has defined
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);

            //override the dependencies with mock ones
            RegisterMockDependencies(config);

            HttpServer server = new HttpServer(config);

            //create a client with a handler which makes sure to exercise the formatters
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new InMemoryHttpContentSerializationHandler(server));

            SchoolyearCreateRequest req = new SchoolyearCreateRequest();

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync<SchoolyearCreateRequest>(baseAddress + "api/schoolyears", req).Result)
            {
                Assert.IsNotNull(response.Content);
                Assert.IsNotNull(response.Content.Headers.ContentType);
                Assert.AreEqual<string>("application/json; charset=utf-8", response.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString());

                SchoolyearCreateRequest recSCR = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<SchoolyearCreateRequest>().Result;

                //todo: verify data
            }
        }

        private void RegisterMockDependencies(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            var unity = new UnityContainer();

            unity.RegisterType<ISchoolyearService, MockSchoolyearService>();

            config.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(unity);
        }
    }

    [RoutePrefix("api/schoolyears")]
    public class SchoolyearController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly ISchoolyearService _service;
        public SchoolyearController(ISchoolyearService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }

        [Route]
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]SchoolyearCreateRequest request)
        {
            _service.CreateSchoolyear(request);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        }
    }

    public class InMemoryHttpContentSerializationHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        public InMemoryHttpContentSerializationHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler)
            : base(innerHandler)
        {
        }

        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            request.Content = await ConvertToStreamContentAsync(request.Content);

            HttpResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

            response.Content = await ConvertToStreamContentAsync(response.Content);

            return response;
        }

        private async Task<StreamContent> ConvertToStreamContentAsync(HttpContent originalContent)
        {
            if (originalContent == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            StreamContent streamContent = originalContent as StreamContent;

            if (streamContent != null)
            {
                return streamContent;
            }

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            await originalContent.CopyToAsync(ms);

            // Reset the stream position back to 0 as in the previous CopyToAsync() call,
            // a formatter for example, could have made the position to be at the end
            ms.Position = 0;

            streamContent = new StreamContent(ms);

            // copy headers from the original content
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>> header in originalContent.Headers)
            {
                streamContent.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value);
            }

            return streamContent;
        }
    }
}
```